# what does this statement evaluate to?

Tags: c#

```
bool myBool = true || UnknownFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

`myBool` will be `true`. .....

Comment: is UnknownFunction() called?
bool myBool = false && UnknownFunction();

Answer (score 1):

Fist it check for `myBool = true` and it is an `|| (or)` condition, compiler wont execute the next statement(`UnknownFunction()`).

If `myBool = false` and condition is `|| (or)` it will check `UnknownFunction()`